# Problema al compilar angular components error NG5002

Tags: angular

Sucede lo siguiente: al cargar el componente específico tal cual lo tengo en la maqueta estática en donde sí funciona la clase skill, en angular me señala errores de sintaxis y no compila correctamente.

En donde puede estar el problema? Comparto código, muchas gracias.

```html
<section class="habilidades">
    
  <h3>Habilidades tecnicas</h3>
  <div class="skill">
  <li><h4>html</h4>
    <span class="bar"><span class="html"></span>
  </li>
  <li><h4>css</h4>
       <span class="bar"><span class="css"></span>
  </li>
  <li><h4>github</h4>
    <span class="bar"><span class="github"></span>
  </li>
  <li><h4>typescript</h4>
    <span class="bar"><span class="typescript"></span>
  </li>
  <li><h4>angular</h4>
    <span class="bar"><span class="angular"></span>
  </li>
      
  </div>

 
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#habilidadesModal">
<i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
</button>
 <!-- Button trigger modal cerrar-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#bannerModal"><i class="fa-solid 
  fa-trash-can"></i></button>

</section>
```

El error marca varias veces lo mismo con la etiqueta `</li>`

```
Error: src/app/components/habilidades/habilidades.component.html:5:1 - error NG5002: Unexpected closing tag "li". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see w3.org/TR/html5/… 5 </li> ~~~~~ ✖ Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues los errores que obtienes como texto y no como imágen. Puedes hacer click en [edit]. Si estás en windows puedes sacar una captura de pantalla con `windows + shift + s`. PD: Si usas MacOs puedes sacar una captura de pantalla con `cmd + 4`.

Comment: Como te decía en el comentario de arriba, agrega el error en tu pregunta. Puedes editarla haciendo click en [edit]

Comment: Agregado!  Saludos

Comment: Hay etiquetas `span` dentro de los `li` que no están cerradas.

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás teniendo es debido a que estás cerrando la etiqueta li antes de cerrar la etiqueta span dentro de ella.

Aca te dejo la corrección para tu código:

```
<section class="habilidades">
  <h3>Habilidades tecnicas</h3>
  <div class="skill">
    <li><h4>html</h4>
      <span class="bar">
        <span class="html"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><h4>css</h4>
      <span class="bar">
        <span class="css"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><h4>github</h4>
      <span class="bar">
        <span class="github"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><h4>typescript</h4>
      <span class="bar">
        <span class="typescript"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li><h4>angular</h4>
      <span class="bar">
        <span class="angular"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </div>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#habilidadesModal">
    <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
  </button>
  <!-- Button trigger modal cerrar-->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#bannerModal">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
  </button>
</section>
```